# How to convert firebase object to array in Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I am new to firebase and I am trying to convert the response from my API call to firebase into an array.

Here is my store file - jobs.js

```
async jobList({ commit }) {
  try {
    const response = await this.$fire.firestore.collection('Job').get()

    response.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(jobs)
      commit('SET_JOBS', jobs)
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
},
```

Here is the response I get in my console.

```
{company_logo: 'tubem Ipsum', salary: 60000, company_name: 'tubem Ipsum', description: 'tubem Ipsum', title: 'tubem Ipsum', …}
 {salary: 7000, title: 'tubem Ipsum', company_logo: 'tubem Ipsum', description: 'tubem Ipsum', tag: 'tubem Ipsum', …}
 {description: 'tubem Ipsum', tag: 'tubem Ipsum', company_logo: 'tubem Ipsum', salary: 40000, company_name: 'tubem Ipsum', …}
{company_logo: 'lorem impsm', description: 'lorem impsm', tag: 'marketing', company_name: 'lorem impsm', salary: 20000, …}
 {salary: 30000, company_name: 'vubem Ipsum', title: 'vubem Ipsum', description: 'vubem Ipsum', company_logo: 'vubem Ipsum', …}
{title: 'tubem Ipsum', company_logo: 'tubem Ipsum', tag: 'tubem Ipsum', salary: 50000, company_name: 'tubem Ipsum', …}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

> maybe different versions have different syntax but if your log is correct this will work

```
const jobs = response.map(item => item.data())
```